# iphone table view-problem with index.section and index.row

Tags: iphone

I have one table view and in each row two radio buttons is there, for selecting the radio button need to calculate the section number and row number and in current logic up to 9th row its working fine but after 9th row it was not changeing the radio button image.

here is my piece of logic implementation code .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell._option1Btn.tag = ((indexPath.section+1)*10)+(indexPath.row+1);
cell._option2Btn.tag = ((indexPath.section+1)*10)+(indexPath.row+1);

    return cell;
}


-(void) respondToRightBtnAction:(UIButton*) sender {
    if(debug)NSLog(@"In the Right button clicked method");
    if(debug)NSLog(@"left button in %d row is YES", sender.tag);

    int section = (sender.tag/10 -1);
    int row = (sender.tag%10 -1);
```

}

Comment: How many rows do you have in each section?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because of the way you are setting your tags. Here is an example.

indexPath.section = 1, indexPath.row = 1
tag = 22

indexPath.section = 0, indexPath.row = 11
tag = 22

A better way to do it is to grab the cell itself, which you can get from the sender variable.

```
-(void) respondToRightBtnAction:(UIButton*) sender {
  UITableViewCell *cell = sender.superview.superview  //actual code will depend on the hierarchy. This assumes that the button is in the contentview of the cell

  NSIndexPath *path = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

  //now you can do whatever you need to do with the indexpath.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in this:

You will have the same tag for **{section = 0, row = 10}** *(tag == 21)* and for **{section = 1, row = 0}** *(tag == 21)*. Try to change the method for generating tags.

For example,

```
cell._option1Btn.tag = ((indexPath.section+1)*1000)+(indexPath.row+1);
cell._option2Btn.tag = ((indexPath.section+1)*1000)+(indexPath.row+1);
```

The coefficient (**1000**) should be smaller then maximum number of rows in sections